# How to get html of parent window tags in child window?

Tags: javascript, html

I am opening a child window from the parent window by the following code :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(){ 
     window.open("child.html","child window");
}
</script>

<body id="data">

<img src = "2.jpg">
<button id="button1" name="NiceButton" onclick="foo()">click here</button>


</body>
</html>
```

In child window I want to get html of parent windows `body` tags . SO I use the following code :

```
        <html>
<head>

</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function capture() {
            window.alert('test');

            html2canvas(window.opener.$("body")
            ,{
                onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            window.open(imgString);  

                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>

<body id="d" onload="capture()">

 <button id="button1" name="NiceButton" onclick="capture()">click here</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
TypeError: window.opener.$ is not a function
```

How can I resolve this error ?

**What do I need :**
I need to get innerhtml of parent windows body tag .Would the following code work ?

```
alert($("window.opener.body")) ;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be including jQuery in your first page.

Comment: I dont need to include jQuery in first page. Jquery is not need in that page .

Comment: ?? But you're referring jQuery on the first page?

Comment: `window.opener.$` is trying to grab hold of the jQuery object on the first page.

Comment: WHere am I refereing jQuery in first page ?

Comment: You're not doing it on the first page, but as Skirtle already stated (and I tried) `window.opener.$` refers to jQuery loaded on the first page. `window.opener` refers to the window object on the first page, and that is used as the context when trying to find `$`, which in your case is not loaded. (`$` seem to be defined though, but is not a function.)

Comment: Yes. I got your point . THanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your capture function with

```
function capture() {
        window.alert('test');

        html2canvas(window.opener.document.body
        ,{
            onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                        var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        window.open(imgString);  

            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: getting error in chrome . "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: You need some host to work this like your localhost, or your domain. You can use xampp, wamp or any web server to host your pages.